# Efficient way to scan struct nested arrays

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, performance

I have a struct that has several arrays members:

```
typedef myData someStruct {
    uint16_t array1 [ARRAY_LENGTH]
    uint16_t array2 [ARRAY_LENGTH]
} myData;
myData testData = {0};  // Global struct
```

At some point in my program I need to set the arrays to some set of predefined values, e.g., set array1 to all 0, array2 to all 0xFF, etc. My first instinct was to write out a for loop something like:

```
void someFunction (myData * test) {
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i) {
        test->array1[i] = 0xFF;
        test->array2[i] = 0xCC;
    }
}
```

However I then reasoned that the actions required by the program to do this would go something like:

```
load address of array1 first position
set value 0xFF;
load far address of array2 first postion
set value 0xCC;
load far address of array1 second position
set value 0xFF;
// and so on...
```

Whereas if I used a separate loop for each array the addresses would be a lot nearer each other (as arrays and structs stored contiguously), so the address loads are only to the next byte each time, making the code actually more efficient as follows:

```
void someFunction (myData * test) {
    uint16_t i = 0;
    for (i; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i)
        test->array1[i] = 0xFF;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i)
        test->array2[i] = 0xCC;
}
```

Is my reasoning correct, is the second one better? Furthermore, would a compiler (say gcc, for e.g.) normally be able to make this optimization itself?

Comment: I assume the array is on the process stack

Comment: nope, struct is global so in flash. Will edit example to make explicit.

Comment: why don't perfer memset like this     memset(&mys.a,0xff,sizeof(mys.a));   
        memset(&mys.b,0xcc,sizeof(mys.b));

Comment: Will memset() not do the same actions? And at the cost of including the string.h lib... (on embedded platform, tight on space)

Comment: I would first ask, if it is a correct assumption that having the addresses close to each other (change by 1 byte instead of 2 bytes) is really an optimization? If you want to consider these kind of optimizations, I would look at loading the address of the first element and then doing pointer arithmetics to go through the array, something like this: uint16_t* p = test->array1; for(){p=0xFF;p+=sizeof(uint16_t);} - though I would again check if this is any optimization.

Comment: If I understand your meaning correctly - for a single loop iteration of one array it's a one byte read difference but 100 iterations with 6 arrays that's 300 byte read difference total.

Comment: I mean: Is the following statement correct: "the address loads are only to the next byte each time, making the code actually more efficient as follows"? [I actually don't know the answer... I would assume that reading a value of the memory from a specific address should take the same amount of time independent of the address value]

Comment: @kripanand memset would set each byte. He needs to set words.

Comment: @MarianV ohh thanks for pointing out . I thought for each byte

Comment: Do the values that you want to place in the array depend on the run or are they fixed beforehand?

Comment: @JensGustedt They are fixed.

Comment: @Toby, so why can't you just initialize them correctly from the start?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. The values to be placed in the arrays in this case are fixed, but as the program runs the get altered, until at some point they may, or may not, be set back to this "preset" set of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to depend on your system architecture.  For example, on, say, a SPARC system, the cache line size is 64-bytes, and there are enough cache slots for both arrays, so the first version would be efficient.  The load of the first array element would populate the cache, and subsequent loads would be very fast.  If the compiler is smart enough, it can use prefetch as well.

On ISAs that support offset addressing, it doesn't actually fetch the address of the array element each time, it just increments an offset.  So it only fetches the base address of the array, once, and then uses a load instruction with the base and offset. Each time through the loop it increments the offset in a register.  Some instruction sets even have auto-increment.

The best thing to do would be to write a sample program/function, and try it.  Optimizations at this low a level require either a thorough knowledge of the CPu/system, or lots of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

My humble recommendation: try and see. One loop solution saves arithmetic operations around increment and test of i. Two loops will probably profit of better cache optimization, especially if arrays are aligned to memory pages. In such case each access may cause a cache miss and cache reload. Personally, if the speed really matters I would prefer two loops with some unfolding.